# Existence of asymptotic variance for an estimator when it doesn't converge to normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, definition, statistical-inference

The definition of an asymptotic variance says:

> For sequence of estimators $\mathbf{U}=(U_1, U_2,\ldots)$, where: $U_i=U_i(X_1,\ldots,X_i)$, if for a sequence of constants $\{k_n\}$:
>           $$k_n(U_n-\theta)\xrightarrow{d.}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$
>           then $\sigma^2$ is the asymptotic variance.

Therefore is this true that an asymptotic variance exists if and only if a normalised estimator (by $k_n$) converges to a normal distribution?

What if an estimator converges to a distribution that is not normal? Then we say the asymptotic variance doesn't exist?

Comment: I presume $\tau^2$ and $\sigma^2$ are meant to be the same thing?

Comment: I'm sorry and thank you for spotting, corrrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider estimating $\theta$ when $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots$ are independent and uniformly distributed in the interval $(0,\theta)$.  The likelihood based on the first $n$ observations is
$$
\begin{align}
L(\theta) & = \begin{cases} \theta^n & \text{if } \theta\ge (\text{all of } X_1,\ldots,X_n), \\ 0 & \text{if } (\text{at least one of }X_1,\ldots,X_n) < \theta. \end{cases} \\[10pt]
& = \begin{cases} \theta^n & \text{if }\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} \le\theta, \\ 0 & \text{if }\max>\theta. \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$
Hence the maximum-likelihood estimator is $\widehat \theta = \max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$.

> **Proposition:** The probability distribution of $(n+1)(\theta-\widehat\theta)$ converges to an exponential distribution with expected value $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Unlike the usual situation with normal distributions one multiplies by $n+1$ rather than by the more slowly growing $\sqrt n$.  The variance of an exponential distribution is proportional to the square of its mean.

**Sketch of proof of the proposition:** Consider the discrete probability distribution of the number of random variables $\theta - X_1,\ldots, \theta - X_n$ that fall within the interval $(0,\theta t/n)$. This is the number of "successes" in $n$ independent trials with probability $t/n$ of success on each trial.  This is a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $t/n$.  As $n\to\infty$ its expected value remains equal to $t$ and hence its distribution approaches a Poisson distribution with expected value $t$.  The distribution of the waiting time until the first arrival in a Poisson process is exponential. $\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: But do we refer to it as an asymptotic variance?

Comment: @marco11 : Actually, now that I think of it, I'm inclined to say that the definition you give was intended for use only in a narrow context, in which the limiting distribution is normal, and one would define an asymptotic variance differently when the limiting distribution is something else.  I was trying to give an example where it would not be normal. $\qquad$

Comment: Could I clarify some things in your answer? (1) Why did you call the variables $\theta-X_1,...,\theta-X_n$ rather than just $X_1,...,X_n$? (2) In the proposition why do we have $(n+1)(\theta-\hat{\theta})$ rather than $(n+1)(\hat{\theta}-\theta)$?

Comment: I think I partially got it. As $\max$ is a biased estimator, for each $n$ the expected value of $\theta-\hat{\theta}$ is $\theta-\frac{n}{n+1}\theta=\frac{1}{n+1}\theta$. Now it should somehow give the distribution of $\theta-\hat{\theta}$ to be $Exp(1/(n+1))$. Could you explain how it is done?

Comment: @marco11 : The discrete random variable that is the number of random variables $\theta-X_1,\ldots,\theta-X_n$ that fall in the specified interval is considered because we want to think about the amount by which $\max$ falls short of $\theta$, and show that a scaled version of that converges in distribution as $n$ grows. $\qquad$

Comment: @marco11 : Here's how Poisson processes work: Let $N_t$ be the number of arrivals before time $t$. Then $N_t$ has a Poisson distribution with expected value $\lambda t$, where $\lambda$ is the average frequency of arrivals, and for $0<t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_m$, the numbers of arrivals in the intervals $[0,t_1],\ [t_1,t_2],\ [t_2,t_3],\ \ldots,\  [t_{m-1},t_m]$ are independent random variables.  Those numbers are $N_{t_1}$, $N_{t_2}-N_{t_1}$, $N_{t_3}-N_{t_2}$, and so on. Each of those independent random variables has a Poisson distribution with expected value proportional$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$to the length of the interval, the length in each case being $t_{k+1}-t_k$.  Now let $T_1,T_2,T_3,\ldots$ be the times of the first, second, and third arrivals, etc.  Notice now that the event $[T_1>t]$ is the same as the event $[N_t = 0]$, and so $$ \Pr(T_1>t) = \Pr(N_t=0) = \frac{(\lambda t)^0 e^{-\lambda t}}{0!} = e^{-\lambda t}. $$ Therefore $T_1$, the waiting time until the first arrival, has an exponential distribution. $\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ and the point is not that $\theta-\widehat\theta$ is exponentially distributed, but rather that the distribution of $(n+1)(\theta-\widehat\theta)$ APPROACHES an exponential distribution as $n\to\infty$. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation, Michael. Now the Poisson process is very clear for me. My only concern is that the exponential distribution (waiting time) does not depend on $t$, so I am not really sure where exactly $(n+1)$ comes into play. I understand that the interval $\theta-\hat{\theta}$ is shrinking to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$, however, how to explicitly show that this rate is going to be $(n+1)$? I'm sorry to bother you.

Comment: The factor $n+1$ makes the expected value of $(n+1)(\theta - \widehat \theta)$ equal to $1$.  Perhaps I should have said explicitly that $\operatorname{E}(\theta - \widehat \theta) = 1/(n+1)$. $\qquad$

Comment: Notice that $$\Pr({\max} \le x) = \Pr( (\text{all of }X_1,\ldots,X_n) \le x) = (\Pr(X_1 \le x))^n = \left( \frac x \theta \right)^n. $$ Differentiating that gives the density function $f_{\max{}}(x) = \dfrac {nx^{n-1}}{\theta^n}$.  Using that, one can find that $$ \operatorname{E}({\max}) = \int_0^\theta x f_{\max{}} (x)\,dx = \frac n {n+1} \theta. $$  Therefore $$ \operatorname{E}(\theta - \max{}) = \frac \theta {n+1}. $$